# DHTMLX Scheduler timeline get cell infos

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

From a scheduler timeline view when I click or doubleClick on a cell I need the collection information, in my case teams, and the date. onCellClick contains the y_ind which may be useful and onEmptyClick contains the date. Is there a way to obtain both information with one event?

Answer (score 1):

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onEmptyClick", function (date, event) {
   console.log(date);
   console.log(scheduler.getActionData(event));
}
```

Now you have all the information from a cell.